# impact of expired domains on search engine ranking

Tags: seo

I wanted to know if buying expired domains has positive impact on SEO or not.
I mean if someone buys an expired domain, and 301 redirect it to his main website, does this trick help ranking?

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure this is on topic here? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281371/which-seo-questions-should-be-closed-as-non-programming-non-admin

Comment: Thank you @ahoffner for your notice. I didn't know this rule.

Answer (score 0):

Buying expired domains and the redirecting them has been an SEO trick for years. Google are aware of it and do stamp it out.

If you think about it it's easy to spot. The sites are not related or the same sector etc.

You also need to ask why the domain expired. Were they link building and have various penalties on the site that they couldn't fix so let the domain drop?

If you buy a site that had issues before such as manual actions, link building etc and then 301 redirect that domain to yours, then those issues then get passed on to your site.

So for me this is very risky and will most likely add benefit to your site whatsoever.

@WilliamHarvey